# Cannot set protocol version on Camel http component URI

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

To disable HTTP connection persistency I would like to enforce HTTP protocol 1.0 on one of my Apache Camel routes using the http component.

Following Camel's [http component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) I tried to use the following URI:

```
http://localhost:8888/foo?httpClient.protocolVersion=HTTP/1.0
```

However, the camel context initialization fails with a ResolveEndpointFailedException with message:

```
Unknown parameters=[{protocolVersion=HTTP/1.0}]
```

I assumed that the protocol version parameter is available due to the [HttpClientParam documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpMethodParams.html#PROTOCOL_VERSION). Interestingly, the soTimeout example from the Apache Camel documentation works fine.

I tried both the http and http4 components. I use Apache Camel 2.10.4. The http component has the user agent Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1.

I know that I could also try to use the httpClientConfigurer and/or clientConnectionManager parameters of the http components, but would rather use a solution that does not require custom code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution.

On the http-component URL I set a custom `httpClientConfigurer`:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo?httpClientConfigurer=myHttpClientConfigurer
```

where `myHttpClientConfigurer`is a bean with an implementation similar to this:

```
public class Http10ClientConfigurer implements HttpClientConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void configureHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
      if (httpClient.getParams() != null) {
          httpClient.getParams().setVersion(new HttpVersion(1, 0));
      } else {
          // Could not set HTTP 1.0 version on httpClient
      }
  }
}
```